# Reentrant Synchronization Goes in Infinite loop

Tags: java, synchronization, reentrancy

When there is reentrant Synchronization, it goes in infinite loop and ends with StackOverflow exception.

The code below prints "Outer" first and then keeps printing "Inner".

Can someone tell me why is this behavior?

```
public void outer()
   {
      synchronized ( this)
      {
         System.out.println("Outer");
         inner();
      }
   }

   public void inner()
   {
      synchronized ( this)
      {
         System.out.println("Inner");
         inner();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error has got nothing to do with `synchronize` keyword. You keep on calling a method recursively without returning. A thread doesn't block itself while trying to acquire lock on the same object. You get *StackOverflowError* because you have run out of max number of stack frames to make calls to `inner()`. This behaviour will be reproduced even without *synchronization*